# Material Design scroll

Tags: android, material-design

Good Day

There is this cool feature on some apps, like Google Play Store, whereby when you open a certain activity, there is a header image on the activity and as you scroll down the header image kind of fades out or the scroll-able content goes over it. A toolbar appears as you scroll up and disappears as soon as you reach the header image. Does anyone know what I am talking about and if so, how does one implement this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called CollapsingToolbarLayout (it's very easy to implement), check new Design Support Library:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.html

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html

Comment: If you've implemented it, can you answer this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30546812/coordinatorlayout-with-recyclerview-collapsingtoolbarlayout